# get an id from several item to use them in an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Let me explain you my issue.

I have a db with several items in it. I did a while loop to display a hidden input with the id of each item as a value. I'd like to get each id of each item to use them in an AJAX request to check something in an other db table.

Here's my while loop:

```
$reqfollow = db_query('SELECT following_id FROM following WHERE follower_id = ?', array($_SESSION['mc']['id']));
    while($follow = $reqfollow->fetch())
        {

$reqitems = db_query('SELECT * FROM items WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY date DESC', array($follow['following_id']));
    while($items = $reqitems->fetch())
            {
?>

    <input type="hidden" class="id" value="<?php echo $items['id']; ?>"> //this is where i have the id of each item

<?php } ?>
```

I have some jQuery to get those ids:

```
function checkingfetchresult(userid){

            $.post("ajax/checkingfetchresult.php", { userid: userid }, //first of all, I check how many item have been displayed, here it is eaqual to 3
            function(check){
            console.log(check); //So 3 here
            for (var i = 0; i<check; i++){
                var id = $(".id").val(); //I try to get the id of each but I only get the first one
                console.log(id); //Only the first one
            }
        });
}
```

But as it is said in my code, I only get the id of the first item. Maybe I should try to do it with an array but if I do it, how will I be able to only get one id at the time of the array to do my other AJAX request which is:

```
function checkinglikebutton(id){



    $.post("ajax/checkinglikebutton.php", { id: id },
            function(check){
            if (check == 1){
                //show the Like button
                $("#dislike").hide();
            }
            else if (check == 0){
                //show the Dislike button
                $("#like").hide();
            }
            else{
                alert('An error has occured');
            }
    });

}
```

I really need help because I'm a bit lost in that.

Here's how I can do it with an array:

```
function checkingfetchresult(userid){

            $.post("ajax/checkingfetchresult.php", { userid: userid },
            function(check){
            console.log(check);
                var id = [];
                $(".id").each(function(){
                    id.push($(this).val());
            });
                console.log(id);
        });
}
```

But I have 3 times the same array :/

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = $(".id"),r=[];
for (var i = 0; i<check; i++){
   var id = ids.eq(i).val();          
   console.log(id); //Only the first one
   r.push(id);
}
return r;
```

Comment: I have each id, but now how can I make them go out of the function to give each of them to a new function ?

Comment: I should be able to console.log(r) out of the function but it's telling me that r is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact solution, but I think you can try something like this:

```
var $inputs = $("input:hidden");
var i = 0;
var ids = [];
$inputs.each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).val());
    i++;
    if (i == check) {
        return false;
    }
});
console.log(ids); //1,2,3,4,5...
```

Then in ajax use ids as:

`$.post("ajax/checkinglikebutton.php", { id: ids.join() },`

Comment: `$("input.ids:hidden");`, and `break` does nothing ids will always contains every inputs value

Comment: I have an error, the console is telling me that the break can't be there: SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch
 

break;

Comment: A weird thing is outputting, I have a 3 times an array, the first one contain on weird 'if' and I don't have the last one. And the two others array contain every ids plus the weird id ...

Comment: It may be due to it reads all the `hidden` fields on the page. Make it more specific by providing the form id as `var $inputs = $("#form-id input:hidden");`

Comment: I've never declared any form in the code, I only put the hidden input

Comment: Then you should write `var $inputs = $("input.id[type=hidden]");`

Comment: The weird id has disappeared but I still have 3 arrays. Is it because check is equal to 3 ?

Comment: Probably the code is being executed 3 times. Depends upon the exact location of this code inside your code.

Comment: Let's say I have only one array, when I'm trying to add id: ids.join() into my other function, it's telling me that ids does not exist. How can I make the array goes out of the previous function ?